# What is Lubuntu default password when it's distributed by magazines?

Tags: password, lubuntu

A friend gave me an old Dell to fix for her daughter. So I put Lubuntu on it. I had a disk with Lubuntu on it that came with one of my magazines, so I installed it. This machine won't boot from USB and has no DVD drive.

So I installed. It seemed to install automatically without any guidance. After about an hour or so a login box appeared. I can only assume it's installed.

What is the default username and password? I didn't have to set one, yet it's asking me for one. I've looked online and couldn't find anything.

Comment: What magazine did it come with? Often times the distros included w/ the magazines are customized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe these are the defaults:

- username: lubuntu
- password: blank (no password)

That's literally nothing, for the password.

#### Linux Format magazine

If you're using the compilation CD/DVD that comes with this magazine the username should be "ubuntu" with again a blank password.

- [Ubuntu 14.04 compilation disc](https://web.archive.org/web/20150921232157/http://www.linuxformat.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=16656)

#### References

- [What is the default user/password?](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/help/faq/using-your-linux/78-what-is-the-default-user-password-)
- [How to disable autologin in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182274/how-to-disable-autologin-in-lubuntu)

Comment: Upvoted! Correct answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Lost_Password

To find the partition on which [L]ubuntu is installed, refer to the [Finding your root partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Finding_your_root_partition) section of the article.

This requires you to still have the installation USB available. Where it says to use the `passwd` command use `passwd <username>` followed by the enter key and type the preferred password twice to make sure password is verified. Sample output of `passwd` command:

```
root@hostname ~:# passwd <username> # and press <return>
Enter new UNIX password:    # Enter new password and press <return>
Retype new UNIX password:   # Re-enter password <return>
```

Then reboot your system.